# Angular.js returning a model from a controller to a form

Tags: angularjs, forms

You can see my code below.

```js
var app = angular.module("appX", []);
console.log(app);
app.controller("orderController", function($scope) {
    $scope.printOption = function(option) {
      var split = option.split('_');
      $scope.quantity = split[0];
      $scope.unitPrice = split[1];
      $scope.total = split[0] * split[1];
      console.log($scope.total);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appX" ng-controller="orderController">
  <div >
    <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
      <select ng-name="optionOne" class="form-control" ng-change="printOption(optionOne)" ng-model="optionOne">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1_12">1 for $12</option>
        <option value="2_22">2 for $22</option>
        <option value="3_29">3 for $29</option>
        <option value="4_35">4 for $35</option>
        <option value="5_40">5 for $40</option>
        <option value="6_45">6 for $45</option>
        <option value="7_50">7 for $50</option>
        <option value="8_55">8 for $55</option>
        <option value="9_60">9 for $60</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col" ng-show="total>0">Total for 8x10 Team and 1 - Individual Photo = {{total | currency}}</div>
  
</div>
```

New to Angular.js I have a form with a number of dropdowns. Each one passes a selected value to my Angular Controller. I'm able to parse the data and return some of the necessary information back to the form. however, I have a number of dropdowns in the form and I want to only provide the appropriate total value of the selection for each dropdown.

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you are trying to ask here.  It appears that this code works correctly as written.  You ask about "multiple dropdowns" but are only showing one in the sample.  is there something wrong with another dropdown you tried to add but aren't showing here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called `console.js` which is showing the console output in the DOM in the JSFiddle you provided. You can just comment out all the `console.log()` as in the below example or remove the library!, Refer the below fiddle.

```js
var app = angular.module("appX", []);
//console.log(app);
app.controller("orderController", function($scope) {
    $scope.printOption = function(option) {
      var split = option.split('_');
      $scope.quantity = split[0];
      $scope.unitPrice = split[1];
      $scope.total = split[0] * split[1];
      //console.log($scope.total);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appX" ng-controller="orderController">
  <div >
    <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
      <select ng-name="optionOne" class="form-control" ng-change="printOption(optionOne)" ng-model="optionOne">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1_12">1 for $12</option>
        <option value="2_22">2 for $22</option>
        <option value="3_29">3 for $29</option>
        <option value="4_35">4 for $35</option>
        <option value="5_40">5 for $40</option>
        <option value="6_45">6 for $45</option>
        <option value="7_50">7 for $50</option>
        <option value="8_55">8 for $55</option>
        <option value="9_60">9 for $60</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col" ng-show="total>0">Total for 8x10 Team and 1 - Individual Photo = {{total | currency}}</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @steverh Were you able to solve your issue with this answer?